# 2005 volvo xc70 radiator fan continuously on high

Tags: volvo

My 05 xc70 wagon has been running fine forever, but recently, the engine cooling fan has been running at high speed continuously, regardless of engine temp.  After some googling, i determined it might be the fan relay, so i went and purchased a fan relay. Upon finding that the fan relay was nowhere to be found in the engine compartment, I did some more googling. Some say that this relay doesn't exist on my model, others say it does, and it's located in an obvious place (directly under nonexistent plastic shield at the front of the engine compartment).  Pics of 2005 xc70 engine compartments vary wildly for some reason.  I can't get my head, or my camera in close enough to read the data on the fan shroud/controller blobs.

In summary, does a 2005 xc70 have a fan relay? If so, where the hell is it? Why does my engine compartment differ from 99% of online photos of xc70 engine compartments?

Comment: Are there different engines available? Are the photos of the other engines?

Comment: It may or may not have a relay, but it will have a thermostatic switch that is more likely the source of the problem. I'd start there.

Comment: fwiw, whichever engine it is, it appears to be this one, based on spinny widgets & hose positioning: https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/2005-Volvo-XC70-Pictures-c5981#pictureId=42600888